# Jquery/JavaScript functions conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want to do is add/remove some class to/from my div. I have made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Megumin/tgowvehx/)...
Im new to js/jquery and I cant undestand why

```
 if ($('.div1').hasClass('active')){
    $('.div1').removeClass('active');

}
```

stop working after I add a second function. Do they conflict with each other or anything? If so is there any way to fix it?
My goal is to achive removing .active while clicking the link or somewhere outside the div.

Comment: Just use toggleClass `$('.div1').toggleClass('active');` Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tgowvehx/2/

Comment: yes they conflict (actually they perform recursive actions), Javascript is executed in the order it is written or otherwise, so the first function removes the class `.active` and when the second function is executed it ads the class back to it.

Comment: If the class is already present your `mouseup` handler is removing it just before the `click` handler runs. Here's one way to fix that: https://jsfiddle.net/tgowvehx/3/

Comment: Immortal Dude, thank you for clear explanation. Is there any solution to achive my goal? Can I somehow connect this two functions?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your `mouseup` event handler and the toggle class functionalities are conflicting. One removes the `.active` class and the other adds it back.

You can add an additional check to your existing `mouseup` handler so that it omits for clicks on `.mylink1` like:

```
if (!e.target.classList.contains("mylink1") && !container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) { ... }
```

Check [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/tgowvehx/4/).

Refer code:

```js
$('.mylink1').click(function() {
  if ($('.div1').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.div1').removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.div1').addClass('active');
  }
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $(".div1");
  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0 && !e.target.classList.contains("mylink1")) {
    $('.div1').removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

.active {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="mylink1">
  Click Me
</a>

<div class="div1">
  <h1>need help :C</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is want i was looking for:))

Answer (score 1):

Probably, what you want is to toggle 'active' class whenever 'clickme' link is clicked. Also, if 'active' class is already added, you want to remove that when clicked anywhere on the document.
For this,

**1) Why your code doesn't work:**

You are using two events, mouseup and click: mouseup is always triggered just before click whenever same element is binded with both of these events. In your case same is happening.

When you click on 'myLink', you actually also trigger mouseup of document. This mouseup event removes 'active' class and click event adds 'active' class. That is why, whenever you click on 'myLink', active class is always added and you always see yellow color background.

**2) Solution: Try using click instead of mouseup for document event binding and event.stopPropagation in click handler of 'myLink'**.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tgowvehx/5/

code:

```
$('.mylink1').click(function(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
    if ($('.div1').hasClass('active')){
        $('.div1').removeClass('active');

    } else {
        $('.div1').addClass('active');
    }

});

$(document).click(function (e)
{

var container = $(".div1");


if (!container.is(e.target)
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
{
    $('.div1').removeClass('active');
}
});
```